# What do the [prompts] mean in bluetoothctl utilty

Tags: bluetooth

I am running bluetoothctl v5.48 on SuSE LEAP 15.1.
The blue prompts [xyz] change from time to time.
For example [CHG] or [device name]. 
What is this telling me? 
I have hunted (without success) for somthing more informative that a web page repeating the "help" command.

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: During a sample **bluetoothctl** session, I will get various prompts. For example:<br/>[NEW]
[bluetooth]
[CHG]
[HM-11]
[agent]
[DEL]